# Abstract class as a type, derived class as instance in C++

Tags: c++, inheritance, tree, iterator, virtual

I am trying to make 3 iterators (3 classes) for a binary tree (one for each traversal) and I want them to share the same base class.

```
class BinaryTree
{
    class Iterator
    {
        virtual Iterator operator++() = 0;
    }

    class Iterator1 : public Iterator
    {

    }

    class Iterator2 : public Iterator
    {

    }

    class Iterator3 : public Iterator
    {

    }
}
```

I have implemented the methods that they share inside the Iterator class. The only methods that differ are the constructors and the overloading of the prefixed ++.

My idea was to make the overloaded operator ++ a virtual function so that it can be overridden by Iterator1, 2 and 3, because I would like to use the iterator like this:

```
for(BinaryTree::Iterator it = t.begin(Preorder); it != t.end(); it++)
{
    // do stuff
}
```

I was used to Java, where you could make an object of an abstract type but instantiate it as another type.
The problem is that in C++ it `cannot allocate an object of abstract type`.
The `begin` method is made using the factory pattern: it returns an object of Iterator 1, 2 or 3 type.

Is there any way around this in order to keep the same syntax as in the `for`?

Comment: use a reference. or with c+11, use `auto` (you don't *really* need polymorphic iterators, do you?)

Comment: have a look at "c++ write iterator", it's a common thing. http://accu.org/index.php/journals/1527

Comment: "I was used to Java, where you could make an object of an abstract type but instantiate it as another type." - You can do the same in C++ perfectly fine, just not with non-pointers or references.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath It doesn't work with c++11 auto: "error: unable to deduce ‘auto’ from ‘<expression error>’"

Comment: Please don't try to smuggle Java idioms into C++. It won't work and the only likely result is frustration and failed projects. If you want to program in Java, for Pete's sake use a Java compiler. If you want to use C++, learn the C++ ways. They are not parallel to Java ways and the reasons of that are deeper than just innate hatred of C++ inventors towards newbies with Java background.

Comment: @n.m. It's not a Java idiom. It's just plain polymorphism. I gave Java just as an example. It's like saying that you can't have infinite streams in Racket, because you have lazy eval. only in Haskell.

Comment: Oh please. Plain polymorphism isn't a Java idiom. Shoving subtyping polymorphism where it doesn't belong **is** Java idiom, and you are not the first one to try it. Subtyping polymorphism doesn't belong in C++ iterators. **If it did we would already have it in the standard library**.

Comment: Oh come'on. There's nothing wrong with polymorphic iterators. Java did a good job. It's just that C++ *prefers* performance over flexibility. They don't want an iterator in the standard library that needs a bloody virtual function call just to access it.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath Nothing wrong with polymorphic iterators indeed, especially when you have no other choice. If C++ would have got a containers library before the advent of templates, it would probably have polymorphic iterators too. But it's got a differently structured library instead. Some people (invariably Java programmers) think it's some kind of horrible mistake and a bit of effort and a couple answers on SO are needed to fix it and replace STL with a Java-esque collections library. They are mistaken, that's all I want to say.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remember, in Java, you don't deal directly with objects, you have pointers to objects. In C++, when you declare a variable of type `x`, you have an `x`, not something that derives from `x`. If you want to use polymorphism, you need either a reference (`x&`) or a pointer (`x*`, `shared_ptr<x>`, `unique_ptr<x>`, ...).

So, your for loop should be

```
for(BinaryTree::Iterator& it = t.begin_preorder(); it != t.end; it++)
```

And `BinaryTree::begin_preorder()` should return a `BinaryTree::Iterator#`, where `#` is the number that corresponds to the correct iterator. It can't return a `BinaryTree::Iterator`, as you cannot have objects of that type (it's abstract). **If it returns a `BinaryTree::Iterator&`, then you won't be able to return a (local) object that was created within the function**, as the object will no longer exist once the function exits. If you return a reference, the actual object the reference points to would have to be cached inside the `t` object.

I assume you want to use polymorphism because you don't necessarily know at compile time which iterator you're going to use (since if you do know at compile time, polymorphism is unnecessary).

If you just want to save some typing in your for loop and don't need polymorphism:

```
for(auto it = t.begin_preorder(); it != t.end; it++)
```

will work fine. Then you don't need the base class or virtual member functions.

Comment: The begin returns a derived iterator, indeed (and not a reference). Could a possible problem be that each of the overloaded ++ (prefixed) returns a pure BinaryTree::Iterator and not a custom one?

Comment: @SilentControl _"The begin returns a derived iterator."_ Then even if `BinaryTree::Iterator` were not abstract, you would still have **object slicing** in your original code.

Comment: @SilentControl That will be a problem, yes. And if `begin` returns a derived iterator, then you won't be able to have it return a different type of iterator based on an argument, as it looks like you're trying to do. (It may appear to be a derived object that's being returned within the function, but if the return type is `BinaryTree::Iterator`, the object will be sliced)

Comment: And whose responsibility is it to clean up after the iterators here?

Comment: It would have to be `const BinaryTree::Iterator& it` if `begin_preorder` returns a temporary.

Comment: Well then... I think that I'll drop the whole polymorphic thing and stick with different iterators... for now.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use pointers or references with polymorphic types:

```
struct Test {
    struct Iterator {
        virtual Iterator &operator++() = 0;
        virtual ~Iterator() = 0;
    };

    struct Forward : public Iterator {
        int i;

        virtual Iterator &operator++()
        {
            i++;
            return *this;
        }
    };

    Iterator *forward()
    {
        return new Forward();
    }
};

int main()
{
    Test t;
    Test::Iterator &it = *t.forward();
    ++it;
    delete &it;
}
```

Getting these things to work more like regular iterators can be done by hiding the polymorphism behind a non-polymorphic wrapper class (the pimpl, or handle-body idiom):

```
class IteratorImpl {
    virtual IteratorImpl *clone() = 0;
    virtual void increment() = 0;
    virtual ~IteratorImpl() = 0;
};
// concrete subclasses

class iterator {
    std::unique_ptr<IteratorImpl> impl;

  public:
    // operator++() based on IteratorImpl::increment

    // copy constructor based on IteratorImpl::clone
};
```